# Web services for iOS application with C# using mysql?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on iPhone application with web services.

Using `HTTP POST` method I tried post the data. But data is saving in database. The response I'm getting is  `404` or `400`. here C# is used instead of PHP.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name=%@,FirstName=%@,DateofBirth=%@,Sex=%@,Country=%@,City=%@,PhoneNumber=%@,IncumbentonPremimum=%@",Name,FirstName,DateofBirth,Sex,Country,City,PhoneNumber,IncumbentonPremimum];

NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[data1 length]];

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:data1];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//This is for Response
NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);`
```

Comment: Current-Type = Content-Type?

Comment: NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name=%@,FirstName=%@,DateofBirth=%@,Sex=%@,Country=%@,City=%@,PhoneNumber=%@,IncumbentonPremimum=%@",Name,FirstName,DateofBirth,Sex,Country,City,PhoneNumber,IncumbentonPremimum]; checked this is passed the correct data

Comment: just change to parse.com, save time

Comment: non-ASCII characters not allowed outside of literals and identifiers. this error i am gettting. i just copied and pasted

Comment: parse.com .. means @JoeBlow

Comment: Current-Type = Content-Type? i dont know difference between these two. @Undeph

Comment: Well, there is no standard header field in HTTP called Current-Type, so I guessed it was a typo. That could be the reason your C#-service is confused and returns http status 400. Anyway - the question you should ask is why your C#-service persists the data, yet it returns an error back to the client.

Comment: oops i need to connect with local database. @JoeBlow

Comment: Hi Rajeev.  My point was "don't do that, change your entire project to using a b.A.A.s. such as parse.com". It is incredibly easy.  100s of examples on the web, since every dot com is moving to this. http://www.raywenderlich.com/19341/how-to-easily-create-a-web-backend-for-your-apps-with-parse  The days of "servers" is done. If your client is using a server, have them change to a bAAs.  I was really just joking about it, but it's the truth.  You could move the entire job to parse.com and the whole thing would be done in 1/10th the time. Consider it!  Cheers!

Comment: No @JoeBlow here i should use only the local host. I don't have rights to change it.

Comment: For sure.  Bear it in mind for the future ok?  In a year the only work around will be bAAs development.